# set z-index for show list on over the <p> text

Tags: html, css

I want to set list `z-index`.

when mouse over list show.
and this list show above `<p>` text
here is simple html and css

```
<style>
ul li{
    display:none;
}
ul:hover li{
    display:block;
    z-index:-1;
}
</style>

<ul><h3>This is LIST</h3>
<li>back</li>
<li>forword</li>
<li>click</li>
</ul>
<p>list show above this text.</p>
```

with this CSS when mouse over the this is list then its wrapped.
 
but I want when mouse over at `This is LIST` then show there list over the `<p>` text.
here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLJN2/)
how its possible.

Comment: A http://www.jsfiddle.net with your code would have been helpful

Comment: @mishik please **never change code in questions**, it might render the whole question pointless many times. If you have code that you think might solve the problem post as an answer.

Comment: If you check the change - you will see that I was changing the idents. That extra `li` style was auto added by the IDE, and it would make more sense to remove it rather that reverting all the indentation.

Answer (score 3):

Z-index applies only to elements that have position 'relative', 'fixed' or 'absolute', not 'static' (which is the default).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is to "preserve" the place for list items even when they are hidden.

For this purpose, use `visibility` CSS attribute instead of `display`:

```
ul li {
    visibility: hidden;
}

ul:hover li {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLJN2/1/).